# Evaluating probabilities on a graph

Tags: probability, graph-theory

Let $G = (V, E)$ be a graph with $|V| = N$ and let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times N}$ bet the adjacency matrix of $G$.
A node of $G$ can't be connected to itself.
Furthermore, $G$ has the property that $\deg(i) \geq 1 ~\forall i \in V$ (every node is connected, at least, to another node).

I perform the following experiment: a node $X$ is randomly drawn from the $G$ and then a node $Y$ is randomly drawn from the neighborhood of $X$ ($N_X$).

I would like to describe the probability $P_{kh}$ (with $(k, h) \in [1, N-1]^2$ since the allowed degrees are between $1$ and $N-1$) that I extract a node $X$ with $\deg(X)= k$ **AND** then I extract another node $Y \in N_X$ with $\deg(Y) = h$. Moreover, I suppose that $Q_k = \sum_{h=1}^{N-1} P_{kh}$ is the probability that $X$ has degree $=k$.

I realized an algorithm for this.
I start with a matrix $P = \left\{ P_{kh} \right\} \in \mathbb{R}^{N-1 \times N-1} = 0_{N-1 \times N-1}$ . I also initialize a variable $d = 0$.
For every couple of node $(i, j)$ such that $A_{ij} = 1$, I increment of $1$ both $d$ and the element $P_{\deg(i)\deg(j)}$ of $P$.
At the end, I divide every element of $P$ by $d$.

I don't know if this is the right way. To validate my algo, I tried to evaluate $Q_k$ but they are equal to the value I expect (obviously $Q_k$ can be easily computed *a priori*).

Someone can give me some suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I figured it out!

Let $D_k \subseteq V$ be the set of node with degree $k$ and let $I(i \in D_k) = 1$ if $i \in D_k$ and $0$ otherwise.
$$P_{kh} = \frac{1}{Nk} \sum_{i \in D_k} \sum_{j \in N_i} I(j \in D_h)$$

We know that $Q_k = \frac{|D_k|}{N}$ and if I try to evaluate it by using $P_{kh}$ then I get:

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
Q_k & = & \sum_{h=1}^{N-1} P_{kh} = \\
& = & \sum_{h=1}^{N-1} \frac{1}{Nk} \sum_{i \in D_k} \sum_{j \in N_i} I(j \in D_h) = \\
& = &  \frac{1}{Nk} \sum_{i \in D_k} \sum_{j \in N_i} \sum_{h=1}^{N-1}I(j \in D_h) = \\
& = &  \frac{1}{Nk} \sum_{i \in D_k} \sum_{j \in N_i} 1 = \\
& = &  \frac{1}{Nk} \sum_{i \in D_k} |N_i| = \\
& = &  \frac{1}{Nk} \sum_{i \in D_k} k = \\
& = &  \frac{1}{Nk} |D_k| k = \frac{|D_k|}{N}.
\end{array}$$

Finally I tried to evaluate the test proposed by joriki. Let $1$ be the only node with degree $1$ and let $2$ be its only neighbor which has degree $N-1$.

$$P_{1,N-1} = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{j \in N_1}I(j \in D_{N-1}) = \frac{1}{N}I(2 \in D_{N-1}) = \frac{1}{N}$$.

What do you think about this? Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

No, that doesn't work. For example, if you have one node with degree $1$ and all others are fully connected among themselves, the probability to get $(1,N-1)$ is $1/N$, whereas your algorithm would produce a number of the order of $1/N^2$.

Comment: thank you. Do you have some suggestion about how to solve this problem?